# Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a question regarding updating data in a table. Here's the code:

```
Dim cmdUp As New SqlCommand("UPDATE TblQuestion SET (QuestionTxt =" + question.Text + ") where QuestionId=@id", conn) 

conn.Open()
cmdUp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", result)

cmdUp.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

an error, Incorrect syntax near '(' appear at line  `cmdUp.ExecuteNonQuery()` .
So , how I want to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the tentative to pass a string value without enclosing it in single quotes. Putting your `question.Text` between single quotes could solve, AT THE MOMENT, the problem.  But this is not the correct way to handle string text used as sql commands.

There is only one way for this kind of scenario. Use a parameterized query (by the way, half of your query is already parameterized, so why not the question text?)

```
Dim cmdUp As New SqlCommand("UPDATE TblQuestion " & _
                            "SET QuestionTxt =@quest " & _
                            "where QuestionId=@id", conn) 

conn.Open()
cmdUp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", result)
cmdUp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quest", question.Text)
cmdUp.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Parameterized queries avoid Sql Injection as explained in other answer but avoid also parsing errors. What happens if your users type a question that contain a single quote? I receive another syntax error.

Comment: Can you use @"" in VB?

Comment: @Ciarán Sorry. you are rigth, fixed now

Answer (score 3):

This will fix your error.

```
Dim cmdUp As New SqlCommand("UPDATE TblQuestion SET QuestionTxt ='" + 
                            question.Text + "' where QuestionId=@id", conn)
```

But you have a *MUCH* bigger problem.  This code will allow SQL Injections attacks.

[image: X"; DROP TABLE TblQuestion;]

HT: http://xkcd.com

Comment: so how do i want to fix this ? any idea?

Comment: A google search on sql injection gives microsoft's excellent article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: when i change to your code just now, the error i get is invalid column name at line cmdUp.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Go to the section "Use the Parameters Collection with Dynamic SQL" -- this will give you the most direct translation from your code.

Comment: @luly then I guess you have an invalid column name.  Are your columns named `QuestionTxt` and `QuestionID`?